# How to write output terminal with tab to the file in shell?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have an executable file that provides a float random number that displays in the terminal such as

./my_exe

Then the output terminal will be

```
0.6
```

Now, I will run the `my_exe` in the loop such as

```
for i in {1..10}
do
./my_exe
./my_exe
./my_exe
done
```

I want to write the output to the file such as the output of command in the same iteration will display in the same row with tab `\t` and the next iters will be in the new line

The output should be

```
0.6 0.7 0.1
0.2 0.2 0.4
...
```

How can I do it in shell file? This is my current code

```
for i in {1..10}
do
./my_exe >> out.txt
echo -e "\t" >> out.txt
./my_exe >> out.txt
echo -e "\t" >> out.txt
./my_exe >> out.txt
echo -e "\t" >> out.txt  #write tab
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf`:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
   printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' $(./my_exe) $(./my_exe) $(./my_exe)
done > out.txt
```

Comment: Great. It worked. If my command is long. I want to break it for easy visualization, can I use `$(./my_exe) \ $(./my_exe) \ $(./my_exe)`

Comment: Yes you can definitely do that.